Integral over Curvature and metric components
Let $(M,g)$ a closed connected oriented manifold of dimension $n=2m$. Furthermore, let $\nabla$ be the Levi-Civita connection and $R$ is the Riemannian curvature tensor. Let $h$ be a symmetric $(0,2)$-tensorfield and $(\partial_i)_{i=1,...,n}$ be a local frame of $TM$. Furthermore,
$\nabla^2_{(\partial_i,\partial_j)}(h)=\nabla_{\partial_i}(\nabla_{\partial_j}(h))-\nabla_{\nabla_{\partial_i} \partial_j}(h).$
Now, I have to consider the following sum, where Einstein convention is used and every index that appears twice is summed from 1 to n:
\begin{align*}
    A_g(h)=\delta_{k_1... k_n}^{j_1 ... j_n} g^{i_1 k_1}g^{i_2 k_2} \nabla^2_{(\partial_{i_1},\partial_{j_2})}(h)(\partial_{i_2},\partial_{j_1})R_{j_4j_3}^{k_3 k_4}... R_{j_n j_{n-1}}^{k_{n-1} k_n},
\end{align*}
here $\delta_{k_1... k_n}^{j_1 ... j_n}$ is the generalized Kronecker delta.
I try to show that
$\int_M A_g(h) dvol_g=0.$
I computed the covariant derivative and got
\begin{align*}
    \nabla^2_{(\partial_{i_1},\partial_{j_2})}(h)(\partial_{i_2},\partial_{j_1})= & \partial_{i_1}(\partial_{j_2}h_{i_2 j_1}-\Gamma^a_{j_2 i_2}h_{a j_1}-\Gamma^a_{j_2 j_1}h_{a i_2}) \\
    - & \Gamma^b_{i_1 j_1}(\partial_{j_2}h_{i_2 b}-\Gamma^a_{j_2 i_2}h_{a b}-\Gamma^a_{j_2 b}h_{a i_2}) \\
    - & \Gamma^b_{i_1 i_2}(\partial_{j_2}h_{b j_1}-\Gamma^a_{j_2 b}h_{a j_1}-\Gamma^a_{j_2 j_1}h_{a b}) \\
    - & \Gamma^b_{i_1 j_2}(\partial_{b}h_{i_2 j_1}-\Gamma^a_{b i_2}h_{a j_1}-\Gamma^a_{b j_1}h_{a i_2}) \\
= & (\nabla_{\partial_{j_1}}(\nabla h))(\partial_{j_2},\partial_{i_2},\partial_{j_1}).
\end{align*}
So I can write this as
$\nabla^2_{(\partial_{i_1},\partial_{j_2})}(h)(\partial_{i_2},\partial_{j_1})= (\nabla_{\partial i_1}(\nabla h))(\partial j_2, \partial i_2, \partial j_1),$
i.e. the covariant derivative of the (0,3)-tensor $\nabla h$.
Therefore, I can write the above integrand as
$A_g(h)=\delta_{k_1... k_n}^{j_1 ... j_n} g^{i_1 k_1}g^{i_2 k_2} (\nabla_{\partial i_1}(\nabla h))(\partial j_2, \partial i_2, \partial j_1)R_{j_4j_3}^{k_3 k_4}... R_{j_n j_{n-1}}^{k_{n-1} k_n}.$
Now, I want to find divergence expressions, since by the divergence theorem the integral is then zero.
But for this I need the components of the inverse of the metric to be $g^{i_1 j_2} g^{i_2 j_1}$ for example so that I can take the trace. But I don't see if it is possible to extract such expressions. And if there are such expressions are there remainder terms?
Can someone point out if my train of thought is right what I am missing? If I need to clarify something just tell me.
